# Set Matlab camera View (Mostly Zoom)

Tags: matlab, camera, movie

So I have a program in matlab that makes a movie. The movie is made up of frames that look like this:

Now the camera angle is set by doing this:

```
campos(1.0e+002 *[1.317650052908556 -1.507231720261665 0.834498724031213]);
```

Those numbers are used by rotating to the correct view with the camera toolbar then using the command:

```
 get(gca, 'CameraPosition')
```

Now I want to set the zoom of the camera. How can I do this?

**Note:** Zooming to the correct position and doing the `get` command described above does not return anyhting differant. It is the same for all zoom positions.

Comment: Have you tried [camzoom](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/camzoom.html)?

Comment: @tmpearce You should add this as an answer, also is there a way to set the zoom to a value rather then zooming from current position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property `CameraViewAngle` to control the zoom of the camera, e.g.

```
set(gca, 'CameraViewAngle', 0.5)
```

to set an angle or

```
get(gca, 'CameraViewAngle')
```

to query the current view angle.